# Azure Kudu - 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created Easy API in Azure app service. I need to install node modules for the API. When i try to install the node modules, i am getting the below error.

> `npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

[image]

Comment: Hi, any progress now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checking if the node and npm paths exist in your system path via

`(ls env:path).value`.

[image]

If not, you could add them into the `path` variable.

```
$env.path = "<nodejs path>;$env.path"
$env.path = "<npm path>;$env.path"
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: On my Azure instance, there is `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\6.9.1` and `D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.8` there. Still, web app fails to start.